# How to convert A to B in C++

Tags: c++

Anyone know how any code can make the 'AB' to 'BC' ?? Something like A+1 = B

```
ZEND_FUNCTION(hello)
{
char *str;
str = 'AB'; 
strcpy (str,str);
puts (str);

RETURN_STRING(str ,0);
}
```

Comment: What is `strcpy(str, str)` supposed to do? What does `'AB'` mean (does it even compile?)? What do `ZEND_FUNCTION(hello)` and `RETURN_STRING(str, 0)` do? In the end, yeah, `'A'+1` will most probably be `'B'`, but if that has anything to do with this madness posted as sample code, I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you are expecting but here something that you might be looking for

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char str[3] = "AB";
    str[0] += 1;
    str[1] += 1;
    cout << str <<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the ASCII code of the character and then  increment it. IF you do char `c = 'b'+1`, you obtain 'c'.

Comment: If the character encoding has contiguous values for alphabetic characters. That's not required.